# Rails + PSQL: How to search through a table with millions of rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, elasticsearch, activerecord, indexing

I am having a PostgreSQL database table where I store all the system logs. Currently, the table has about 5.5M rows. This is its structure:

```
create_table "app_logs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "admin_id"
    t.datetime "received_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string "admin_name"
    t.string "event_type"
    t.jsonb "event_data"
    t.string "trackable_type"
    t.integer "trackable_id"
    t.index "date(received_at)", name: "index_activity_logs_date_received_at"
    t.index ["admin_id"], name: "idx_18712_index_activity_logs_on_admin_id"
    t.index ["event_type"], name: "index_activity_logs_on_event_type"
    t.index ["received_at"], name: "index_activity_logs_on_received_at"
    t.index ["trackable_type", "trackable_id"], name: "index_activity_logs_on_trackable_type_and_trackable_id"
  end
```

And this is how I try to retrieve data from the table (and the attempt ends up with an error - too long to respond/return data):

```
@data = AppLog
        .by_event_type(params[:event_type])
        .by_admin(params[:admin_id])
        .by_date_from(params[:logs_from])
        .by_date_to(params[:logs_to])
        .page(params[:page]).per(100)
        .order('received_at DESC')
```

Can I manage such a structure with Rails + PostgreSQL (and proper indexing) or would be more appropriate (and scalable) to focus on a 3rd party solution, such as Elastic?

Comment: What column is the date from/to using? `received_at`? You don't have any rows in your table so it should be basically instant.

Comment: Yes, it does use the column `received_at`. I don't understand the second part - `You don't have any rows in your table so it should be basically instant.` - in the table is around 5.5M rows.

Comment: 5.5M rows is nothing. You should use explain/analysis on the query to see why it's slow.

Comment: Add an index that contains all the used columns: `add_index :app_logs, [:event_type, :admin_id, :received_at], name: :app_logs_search_index`; this will index the records in a better way and retrieve the data faster.

Comment: Add the output of 
AppLog
        .by_event_type(params[:event_type])
        .by_admin(params[:admin_id])
        .by_date_from(params[:logs_from])
        .by_date_to(params[:logs_to])
        .page(params[:page]).per(100)
        .order('received_at DESC').explain
to the question